# Measuring a plant's electric activity any instructions where to place electrodes?

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, electrophysiology

I would like to measure a plant's electric activity / voltage, I've looked online to find out where to place the electrodes and what type of electrodes to use but they seem to very wildly.  Any ideas?

At the moment

1. I plan on wiring one end of a needle to the stalk and one end to the soil.
2. The connections from the plant would go to a laptop mic input to record the signal then I would normalize the signal.
3. I would then process the signal in MATLAB/Octave using FFT.

Any thoughts or videos on connecting the electrodes to the plants or trees?

I did find this [Development of Bio-Machine Based on the Plant Response to External Stimuli](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jr/2011/124314/)

Comment: A quick glance on Google scholar only revealed plant-electrophysiological studies deploying single-cell recordings. You can't do single-unit recordings in an intact plant with your sound card connected to a needle. What potentials are you exactly planning on measuring? Without specification of your target potential this question cannot be easily answered (that is, not by me :-)

Comment: Further, I strongly doubt that the amplification of the AD converter is sufficient, and the amount of noise in the signal will probably sky rocket due to your setup being poorly isolated.

Comment: I vote to close as OP has not edited and clarified question after comments

Comment: I'm looking to measure voltage

Comment: And how would you use FFT to analyze it? You are expecting oscillating activities in single cells recorded with your sound card? It all doesn't line up...

Comment: Import the signal into matlab or octave and use their FFT function to analyze it (see #3 from question)

Comment: What they do in the linked paper is injecting current and recording it back. Is that what you want? FYI: The paper, and journal for that matter, sorry to say, is of exceptional low quality.

Comment: If you could add more detail as to what you wish to record that would be great. I'm happy to upvote this question once it is clear, and more than happy to attempt an answer once I know what you are exactly after.

Comment: I found this link that has a lot of good info and directions [http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835954/](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835954/)

Comment: @AliceD thanks I'm going over some of the papers I found online at the moment to see which electrodes they use. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835954/

Comment: The roots of plants have been used more often than the actual stem of the plant e.g. http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/es071938w

Comment: I would love to get more info about the roots and signal activity but the link you provided requires me to pay along with the title being about "Microbial Fuel Cells Generating Electricity from Rhizodeposits of Rice Plants"  and the abstract being very brief

Comment: Perhaps you will find what you are looking for in the closing report of the FP7 project that funded the article. http://cordis.europa.eu/result/rcn/140451_en.html